# ANSI escape codes not moving cursor horizontally

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to make a text editor in the terminal with node and typescript but the ansi escape codes aren't moving the cursor horizontally. THe cursor moves vertically correctly but it just wont move horizontally.

Code: (index.ts)

```
var width = process.stdout.columns;
var height = process.stdout.rows;

function dupe(input: string, length: number) {
    var newI = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        newI += input
    }

    return newI
}

function pad(pad: string, input: string, width: number): string {
    var space = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < width - input.length; i++) {
        space += pad
    }

    return input + space;
}

var stdin = process.stdin;

// without this, we would only get streams once enter is pressed
stdin.setRawMode( true );

// resume stdin in the parent process (node app won't quit all by itself
// unless an error or process.exit() happens)
stdin.resume();

// i don't want binary, do you?
stdin.setEncoding( 'utf8' );

// on any data into stdin
stdin.on( 'data', function( key ){
  // ctrl-c ( end of text )
  if ( key.toString() === '\u0003' ) {
    process.exit();
  }
  // write the key to stdout all normal like
  update(key.toString())
});

function setpos(x: number, y: number) {
    return `\x1b[H\x1b[${y}B\x1b[${x}C`
}


var mousex = 0;
var mousey = 0;

async function update(key: string) {
    key = key.toLowerCase();

    width = process.stdout.columns;
    height = process.stdout.rows;

    console.clear()

    console.log(dupe('-', width))
    
    for ( var i = 1; i <= height-2; i++ ) {
        process.stdout.write(`${pad(' ', i.toString(), 3)}|This is a test string\n`)
    }
    if (key === 'w') { mousey --;}
    if (key === 's') { mousey ++;}
    if (key === 'a') { mousex --;}
    if (key === 'd') { mousex ++;}
    
    if (mousey < 0) { mousey = 0}
    if (mousey > height) { mousey = height}
    if (mousex < 0) { mousex = 0 }
    if (mousex > width) { mousex = width}
    console.log(setpos(mousex, mousey))
    console.log(`\x1b[1A${mousex} ${mousey} ${width} ${height}`)
}

update('')
```

*stack overflow why do i need to write more i literally have nothing else to write.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I was just dumb and didn't just try a different package.
Installing `terminal-kit` fixed my problem.